# Keep ASP.NET site and content separate

Tags: iis, asp.net, html

I have an ASP.NET site in folder x.  Currently lots of other static content gets added to folder x and gets mixed in, making it one big mess.  I would like to keep the ASP.NET site and the content separate somehow.

I know you can create virtual directories in IIS, but there are LOTS and even some content in the root.  The content people are not technical and really need an easy way to add it.  I would stick everything in a subfolder (they don't touch anything outside, I don't touch their folder), but that would change their URLs (www.example.com/something to www.example.com/content/something).

I almost need a way to "merge" two folders and have them act as one.  I'm guessing that is impossible since there could be file conflicts, etc.  Any other ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On IIS7, you can download and install the [URL Rewrite module](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/) which may be able to take care of some of this for you.  You could move the static content files to a sub-folder and rewrite those requests to fetch the content from the new location while leaving the URLs intact.